# Flatten JSON value as key

Tags: json, go, flatten

I try to transform a JSON of the form:

```json
{
  "name" : "John",
  "value" : [ "age" : "25"]
}
```

...into:

```json
{
  "John": ["age" : "25"]
}
```

But I can't find a way to do it. Any advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go/Golang, Flatten a Nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642575/go-golang-flatten-a-nested-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution might look something like this:

```
parsed := map[string]interface{}{}
_ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(unparsed), &parsed)
data, _ := json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{
    parsed["name"].(string): parsed["value"],
})
```

See this Playground to see the code working: https://play.golang.org/p/1JFxBE6dFzp

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was thinking of in my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want array of age then use

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "value": [
    {
      "age": "25"
    }
  ]
}
```

else use (which is more logical)

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "value": {
    "age": "25"
  }
}
```

Comment: i want to transform 
{
  "name": "John",
  "value": {
    "age": "25"
  }
}
as 
{
  "John":
    {
"age": "25"
}
}