# Go Gorm Gin Json

Tags: json, go, web, go-gorm, go-gin

I have a structure that contains another structure. This structures represent the tables in my DB. I define connections between them through Gorm tags. As the result, when I pass this structure as json with Gin, I have something like this:

```
{
"field1":"value1",
"field2":"value2",
enother_structure {
    "field1":"value1",
    "field2":"value2",
  }
}

But I need to have a flat json like this:

{
"field1":"value1",
"field2":"value2",
"enother_field1":"value1",
"enother_field2":"value2",
}
```

Now I use converters like in Java. For example:
func (s *Structure) ConvertAariToAa(es *FlatJsonStructe)

```
{
  *es = FlatJsonStructure{
    "field1":s.field1,
    "enother_field1":s.enother_structure.field1,
    ...
 }
}
```

But if I have too much field it's too much this kind of work. I didn't find a convenient was how to solve this.

Comment: You should implement a custom JSON marshaller interface on the types, or just write a function to flatten, which you'll find all over the place. Voting to close as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/24642575/1230836

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to flatten nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642575/how-to-flatten-nested-json)